# Converting a multi-level hash into a single hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a source hash:

```
a = {'1' => 'A',
     '2' => 'B',
     '3' => 'C',
     '4' => { '5' => 'D', '6' => 'E', '7' => { '8' => 'F', '9' => 'G' }},
     '10' => {'11' => 'H'}}
```

I need to construct a method to make it a flat hash (single hash). The result should look like:

```
a = {'1' => 'A', '2' => 'B', '3' => 'C', '5' => 'D', '6' => 'E', '8' => 'F', '9' => 'G', '11' => 'H'}
```

I tried with `merge`, `deep_merge`, `each_with_object`, and `recursion`, but they did not give proper results.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: updated the question! @kabanus: Didn't see that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'1' => 'A',
     '2' => 'B',
     '3' => 'C',
     '4' => { '5' => 'D', '6' => 'E', '7' => { '8' => 'F', '9' => 'G' }},
     '10' => {'11' => 'H'}}

# recursive detect value is Hash or not
compact_hash = ->(hh, h0={}) {
    hh.reduce(h0) do |h, (k, v)|
        if v.is_a? Hash
            compact_hash[v, h]
        else
            h[k] = v
            h
        end
    end
}

puts compact_hash[a]
```

---

Many thanks to @cary, I knew how to do one-line without `;` and remove `h`.

```
compact_hash = ->(hh, h0={}) {
    hh.each_with_object(h0) { |(k, v), h | v.is_a?(Hash) ? compact_hash[v, h] : h[k] = v }
}
```

Comment: Nice recursion. It's worth noting that the corresponding recursive method is obtained by replacing the first line with  `def compact_hash(hh, h0={})` and the last (`}`) with `end`. Also if you use `hh.each_with_object(h0) do |(k, v),h|` you can get rid of that pesky line `h` (and perhaps make it a ternary statement).

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you very much! That `h` bugs me.

Comment: Whenever I receive a suggestion that would improve my answer, I rewrite my answer from scratch and thank the commenter in a comment. I think that better serves the reader than keeping the content of my original answer and noting the suggested improvement. All of us would do that (except perhaps the attribution) if we were writing a book or blog that we had circulated in draft form for comment, so why not for an SO answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { '1' => 'A', '2' => 'B', '3' => 'C',
      '4' => { '5' => 'D', '6' => 'E', '7' => { '8' => 'F', '9' => 'G' } },
     '10' => { '11' => 'H'} }

hh = h.dup    
loop do
  g = hh.select { |_,v| v.is_a? Hash }
  break hh if g.empty?
  g.keys.each { |k| hh.delete(k) }
  g.values.each { |f| hh.update(f) }
end
  #=> {"1"=>"A", "2"=>"B", "3"=>"C", "5"=>"D", "6"=>"E", "11"=>"H", "8"=>"F", "9"=>"G"}
```

This does not mutate `h`:

```
h #=> { "1"=>"A", "2"=>"B", "3"=>"C",
  #     "4"=>{"5"=>"D", "6"=>"E", "7"=>{"8"=>"F", "9"=>"G"}},
  #    "10"=>{"11"=>"H"}}
```

The antepenultimate line could be replaced by the following.

```
g_keys = g.keys
hh.delete_if  { |k| g_keys.include?(k) }
```

I don't know which would be the more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'1' => 'A',
     '2' => 'B',
     '3' => 'C',
     '4' => { '5' => 'D', '6' => 'E', '7' => { '8' => 'F', '9' => 'G' }},
     '10' => {'11' => 'H'}}

def flatten_hash(hash)
  hash.each_pair.reduce({}) do |h, (k, v)|
    v.is_a?(Hash) ? h.merge(flatten_hash(v)) : h.merge(k => v)
  end
end

# pry(main)> flatten_hash(a)
#=> {"1"=>"A", "2"=>"B", "3"=>"C", "5"=>"D", "6"=>"E", "8"=>"F", "9"=>"G", "11"=>"H"}
```